# ImageMorph squeak\smalltalk turn image

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I have an ImageMorph and I want to set the image in diagonal.
Is there any way to do it?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Yes, there is. What have you tried so far? Please see [ask].

Comment: I've tried to use position, then I tried topLeft, bottomRight.... nothing work:( actually I have to simulate snooker cue....

Comment: please tell me how? I stack with a project in my studies :(

Comment: Please post the code you've been using and explain in detail what you've tried (edit your question to do that, don't post comments). I understand that you're stuck but we won't do your homework for you.

Comment: It's not what I ment! Just want to know the basic how can I take an ImageMorph and turn it around?

Comment: "set the image in diagonal" and "turn it around" aren't very clear  transformation verbs. Do you mean mirror image (about the diagonal)? Or something else?

Comment: @user3132295 can you please share with me the code for the snookergame? I am also stuck in my studies with this project.ryummail-stack at yahoo com

Answer (score 2):

You Alt-click the morph to bring up its halo, then drag the blue rotation handle to rotate it. This is the same for any morph, not just `ImageMorphs`.

Programmatically you can send `heading:` to your morph giving its new angle in degrees.

Comment: Bert Freudenberg Thank you so much it's so simple! I found out that the position is updated to :)
Finally someone who understood whet I ment to :)